# How do I calculate the proper fan size for a bathroom exhaust and the number of pickups?

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent

Getting ready to remodel my bathroom and I'm thinking about installing an inline fan to reduce noise. I'm looking at Panasonic 120 and 240cfm models.

Bathroom is 7' x 8' x 8'. With a shower in one corner, and a toilet in the opposite corner.

How many CFM do I need? Does it make sense to install a Y, and separate pickups over the bath and toilet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual rule of thumb is to equate square footage to CFM.

7x8= 56 SF => 56 CFM.  Rounding up to 80 is typical.

Y'd pickups are nice.

The ceiling mounted Panasonics are plenty quiet, though (meaning just 1 pickup).  I prefer exhaust fan closest to (or in) the shower (new Panasonic with recessed light is very nice) and connected to a countdown timer.

Be sure to have any shower electrics run from a GFCI.